# Windows Server 2016 installation hangs on new SSD

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, dell-poweredge, ssd

I hope Server Fault is the right place to ask, move to Super User if that is more appropriate.

I am trying to do what I thought would be a simple upgrade of Windows Server 2012 to 2016 with a new SSD instead of HDD on a Dell PowerEdge 220.

When I select the unallocated space drive and click next it just hangs forever with the hourglass cursor. I tried disconnecting the old HDD. 
[image: new partition]

I tried formatting the drive through Windows. Then when I select that partition during setup, it gives me the "the selected disk is of gpt partition". So I delete the partition. When I click Format it hangs again.
[image]

I updated the Dell firmware and changed bios to uefi. The new SSD is Samsung 860 Pro. I tried everything and looked everywhere for 2 days, the closes I found was this:
https://superuser.com/questions/444141/why-is-windows-not-able-to-create-a-system-partition
Nothing works, please help.

Comment: What install media are you using? (USB stick, DVD?) Is your new SSD SATA or PCIe? How long have you waited for the format to complete?

Comment: I tried both DVD and USB. Waited about half an hour. There is no progress or indication, just hourglass icon.

Comment: Does your Dell have the pre-boot diagnostic tool available from the F12 boot menu? If so, have you tried running a hardware diagnostic on your SSD?

Comment: Tried it, finds the drive and passes successfully.